# Programming a flow in Twilio Programmable Number

Tags: python, api, twilio, twilio-api

I want to program a simple flow using Twilio's programmable number using voice. I want to ask user 4 questions and based on the 1st question (either yes or no) ask a different question and based on 2nd question (either yes or no) ask a different question and so on.

So far, I've the following:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse, Gather
import twilio

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/voice", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def voice():
    """Respond to incoming phone calls with a 'Hello world' message"""
    # Start our TwiML response
    resp = VoiceResponse()

    # Read a message aloud to the caller
    resp.say("Welcome to chatbot!", voice='alice')
    # Start our <Gather> verb
    with resp.gather(numDigits=1, action="/handle-key", method="POST") as g:
        g.say("""For sales, press 1. 
                 For marketing, press 2.
                 """)
    print (resp)
    return str(resp)

@app.route("/handle-key", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def handle_key():
    """Handle key press from a user."""

    digit_pressed = request.values.get('Digits', None)
    resp = VoiceResponse()
    print (digit_pressed)
    resp.say("You pressed " + str(digit_pressed))

    return str(resp)

@app.route('/sales', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def sales():
    pass

@app.route('/marketing', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def marketing():
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My question is do I've to make new functions for each gather action or I can collect the digit pressed/ text (from speech of what user said) in the initial view (function voice)

I've spent considerable time on this question and have not been able to come up with a definite answer.

Comment: You could use a querystring parameter to make things generic and control the flow.

Comment: Hi @DannyG - could you please share examples of what are you talking about?

Comment: I used this to create a simple one-way interaction b/w the bot and user, https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/automated-survey-flask

but this still does not solve my purpose as I need to create a flow.